# Incrementing a variable with the value in front of text in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm coding Selenium scripts for automatically testing a signup process.

I have two variables that need to be incremented and stored to be used in future sessions so the scripts can be used again and again without these unique key items being re-used, which would generate an error.

Where I'm getting tripped up is that the primary variable I need to increment is on the front of a text string, not the back, so `suffix++` won't work.

For various reasons I cannot explain logically, the emails MUST be formatted like this:

`XXXXtest@email.com`

So, let's say I'm starting with `1000test@email.com`, I'd want to increment to 1001test@email.com the next time the script is run.

I'm a relative newbie to Selenium (but not to automated testing) and -completely- without Javascript knowledge.

Comment: What are you implementing this test in? What you describing seems to be simply concatenating a variable, let's say `x` with a string, let's say `test@email.com`, but I'm assuming there's more to it than that because you mention you have previous programming knowledge.

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium IDE look at this link [How to add random to variable](http://webigniter.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/storing-variables-in-selenium-ide/)

Example for Selenium IDE:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth()+1; var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); var hour = today.getHours(); var min = today.getMinutes(); if(dd&lt;10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm&lt;10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy+ '-'+hour+'-'+min+'-' + Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);}</td>
    <td>number</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${number}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

number = "11-08-2013-10-10-10" today date + random number